# What is the difference between @TestOnly and @VisibleForTesting in unit test

Tags: java, annotations, guava, encapsulation, jetbrains-ide

As per my understanding, these annotations used for methods with an access modifier that allows method invocation from another class for unit testing

@VisibleForTesting - com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting
@TestOnly - org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **not** for the same thing.

[`@VisibleForTesting`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jetbrains/annotations/latest/org/jetbrains/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html) is used for a methods that could be private/package-visible but has a higher visibility so it can be used by tests. Such a method can still be called in Production.

[`@TestOnly`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jetbrains/annotations/latest/org/jetbrains/annotations/TestOnly.html) is used for a method that can **only** be used by tests, for instance to create a stub or to perform an additional validation only when testing. Such a method should never be called in Production, although the annotation won't prevent that.

By the way, JetBrains provide both annotations, so they can be used in the same project.

Answer (score 6):

The first big difference is obviously that it's provided by different projects.

`@VisibleForTesting` is part of the [Google Guava libraries](https://guava.dev/) and `@TestOnly` is part of [JetBrains annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html) which are associated with JetBrains, the makers of IntelliJ IDEA, among others.

Comparing the JavaDoc of the two shows that they serve basically identical goals: [`@TestOnly`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.jetbrains/annotations/latest/org/jetbrains/annotations/TestOnly.html) and [`@VisibleForTesting`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html).

Note that the documentation of **both** annotations contain a note effectively warning you that the annotation itself does not prevent production code from calling the annotated method. JetBrains suggests the use of static checking tools that support that annotation (one of which is presumably built into IntelliJ IDEA) and Guava suggests the use of external checker tools with an explicit list of forbidden APIs.

**tl;dr** They indicate effectively the same thing. The decision which one to use depends mostly on which tools you are using to act on them and which one they support. Already using other annotations or classes from one of those packages is another reason to pick one over the other.

Comment: This is slightly inaccurate; they do have different meanings and the JetBrains annotations project even has both annotations `@VisibleForTesting` and `@TestOnly`; see @benjamín-valero's answer for the difference.